# Situações de uso dos escopos do Apache Maven

Tags: apache, maven, dependências

A pergunta é sobre os diferentes valores que podem ser atribuídos a propriedade `<scope>` das dependências do Apache Maven, e que critérios devo estabelecer para a utilização de cada um deles.

O Apache Maven possui os seguintes escopos: **compile**(default), **import**, **provided**, **runtime**, **system** e **test**.

Eu quero saber o que eu devo levar em conta na hora de usar cada um desses escopos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Compile

O pacote é considerado na compilação. Se houver empacotamento, a dependência é inclusa no pacote.

### Provided

O pacote é considerado na compilação, mas não é incluso no pacote se houver empacotamento.

### Import

Só funciona para dependências do tipo `POM` na parte `<dependencyManagement>` do seu arquivo `pom.xml`. Basicamente inclui todas as dependências contidas dentro do `POM` da dependência no seu `POM`.

### Runtime

Indica que a dependência não precisa estar na compilação, mas precisa estar na execução.

### Test

Indica que a dependência é usada apenas na fase de testes.

### System

Semelhante ao `provided`, mas para JARs. Os JARs precisam ser especificados explicitamente.

Mais aqui: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Sobre o que se levar em conta para a utilização de cada um, isto fica mais claro à medida que você empacota sua aplicação e alguns erros aparecem. Por exemplo, o escopo `provided` é bem utilizado quando os pacotes pertencem a alguma `lib` padrão de um servidor de aplicação específico, como o JBoss ou o WebLogic, em que os pacotes não existem em um repositório Maven, mas eles precisam ser validados em alguma etapa de desenvolvimento.

Comment: Primeiramente, obrigado por responder. Uma curiosidade, servidores de aplicação bem conhecidos como o Wildfly, Glassfish, WebLogic, etc., apresentam todas as tecnologias do JavaEE(JPA, JTA, EJB, JSF, etc.)? Ou cada servidor dispõem somente de algumas dessas tecnologias da JavaEE?

Comment: Cada um possui uma variedade de tecnologias dependendo, inclusive, da versão de cada servidor. Vale a pena consultar as páginas de especificações, inclusive, para economizar na hora de fazer seu POM.